# How to use deriving and batteries at same time in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, deriving, ocaml-batteries

So basically in my project I need to use `batteries` (for `File.lines_of` and other related functions) and `deriving` (for `Show.show`) at the same time.

However, when I use `opam` to install package `deriving` on my Mac, it seems that it will firstly remove the `batteries` package, after that it will start to install `deriving`..

and when install `batteries` using `opam`, it will firstly remove `deriving`...

Is there anything wrong with my configuration..? Or it is just the normal case..? THen how can I use `batteries` and `deriving` at the same time?

[image]

Comment: Please provide output of `opam install deriving batteries`. Writing both at the same time should cause opam to state that the constraint is unsolvable, if indeed the two libraries are incompatible. Also, just give text output; no good reason for a screenshot for plain text.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal OMG... `opam` didn't claim any inconsistent and successfully install both two packages... thank you... but anyway, why I can't install deriving and batteries one by one using `opam`..?

Comment: The solver doesn't get things quite right sometimes. There has been a lot of work to improve things. See [here](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2014-04/msg00138.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I've had no problem installing both libraries (batteries 2.1.0 and deriving 0.5) with OCaml 4.00.1 (and Opam 0.9.6)
- You might want to check this question: [opam upgrade wants to downgrade a bunch of packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594555/opam-upgrade-wants-to-downgrade-a-bunch-of-packages) -- not sure whether this is relevant, but it seems that it might be.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi bienvenu, I update my question with a picture... Is there any configuration wrong with my `opam`?